# How to run locally installed npm package with npx

Tags: npm, cypress, npx

I have the following folder structure with the *locally installed* Cypress module:

```
cypress-test-project
  node_modules
     cypress
  tests.spec.js
```

As I read it in this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/npm-vs-npx-whats-the-difference/), npx helps to execute globally and locally installed packages:

> Run a locally installed package easily
>
> If you wish to execute a locally installed package, all you need to do
> is type:
> $ npx your-package
> npx will check whether  or
>  exists in $PATH, or in the local project  binaries, and if
> so it will execute it.

As I have Cypress installed in the node_modules folder, I tried to run the following command:

> npx cypress open

This is what I get:

> No version of Cypress is installed in:
> C:\Users\main\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.1\Cypress
>
> Please reinstall Cypress by running: cypress install
>
> Cypress executable not found at:
> C:\Users\main\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.1\Cypress\Cypress.exe
>
> ---
>
> Platform: win32-x64 (10.0.22000) Cypress Version: 9.5.1

Why does npx stop after checking the PATH variable and ***not looking*** in the local folder?

Answer (score 1):

Cypress **always** installs to that user-specific (global) location even if you install locally in the project.

It sounds like the install crashed part way.

Try removing and repeating.

Comment: If Cypress is always installed globally, then what't the point of its _locally_ installed version?

Comment: I have no idea, just telling you how it is. If I was to guess, I'd say 1) the scope of the tool is massive so having the cache means less overhead per project. 2) You can run different versions in different projects.

Comment: But if I _can't run_ different local versions as always the global cached version is used, then the local version (even if different) is just a waste of space.

Comment: The cache contains all versions loaded, there's not one "global cached version". It would be better if you just try it out and take a look.

Comment: I installed it again and it worked. So I guess, the _node_modules_ folder contains some related libraries. Still confused about what local packages mean in this case... :)